# Error when importing vcard. Vcard generated with python for range or area codes to block spammers

Tags: python, ios, macos, contacts, vcf-vcard

So Im trying to make a vcard to block spammers from a given area code range, but after creating the vcard, it fails to load into mac or iOS contacts.

The template vcard looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.6//EN
N:;Spamers;;;
FN:Spamers
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:5555550000
TEL;type=OTHER;type=VOICE:555555-0001
X-ABUID:5E9A1363-5432-4463-9389-925B40FB3C29:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

I then insert some more lines with this python code:

```
In [13]: s="TEL;type=OTHER;type=VOICE:55555%d-%04d\n" 

In [24]: f=open('Spamers.vcf','a')

In [25]: for j in range(10):
   ....:     for k in range(10000):
   ....:         if ((j==5) and (k==5555)): 
   ....:             pass
   ....:         else:
   ....:             f.write(s % (j,k))
   ....:             

In [26]: f.close()
```

And then move the last two lines to the bottom. But as I said above, this vcard is corrupted for whatever reason, and will not import into mac or iOS contacts.

Answer (score 0):

seems like neither can handle large contact lists. aprox 1000 is the breaking point...this code worked for me

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
from numpy import remainder,floor,sum

number= "5555555555"
noblockList=[]
noblockList.append(number)

digrang="0000012222"
digrangArray=[]
combPow=0
for i,(sn,sdr) in enumerate(zip(number,digrang)):
    if sdr!='0':
        combPow+=1
        digArray=[]
        for j in range(max([0,int(sn)-int(sdr)]),min([10,int(sn)+int(sdr)+1])):
            digArray.append((j-int(sn))*10**(9-i))
        digrangArray.append(digArray)
digrangArray=sum(cartesian(digrangArray),1)+int(number)

headS="""BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.6//EN
N:;Spamers%d_DigiRange;;;
FN:Spamers%d_DigiRange\n"""

footerS="""X-ABUID:0B4EBF58-D295-49FC-B850-85C8D97870FF:ABPerson
END:VCARD\n"""

s="TEL;type=OTHER;type=VOICE:%010d\n" 

f=open('Spamers_%d_DigiRange.vcf' % (int(number[:5])),'w')
f.write(headS % (int(number[:5]),int(number[:5])))
f.write("TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:%010d\n" % (digrangArray[0]))



for dra in digrangArray[1:]:
    if any([(dra==int(num)) for num in noblockList]):  
        pass
    else:
        f.write(s % dra)
f.write(footerS)
f.close()
```